# Roots of quadratic..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\cos^4 a + k$ and $\sin^4 a + k$ are the roots of $x^2 + A(2x + 1)= 0$ and $\sin^2 a + 1$ and $\cos^2 a + 1$ are the roots of $x^2 + 8x+ 4 = 0$, then the sum of the possible values of $A$ is?
Are the given roots of the second equation even possible in this case?

Comment: No. Your conjecture is correct. The sum of the roots of the 2nd equation is 3, not -8 (as it would have to be if they were the roots of the equation given). So this scenario is impossible.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Where did you find this question - perhaps there's an error  somewhere compared to the original source.